# How to change current-context

Tags: kubespray

I use kubespray installed Kubernetes Cluster. I defined the cluster name as cluster.devops in the file, `group_vars/k8s-cluster/k8s-cluster.yml`. After the Kubernetes Cluster installed. the current-context in kube confi file is `kubernetes-admin@cluster.devops`. I would like the current-context is cluster.devops,

i.e. current-context is same as cluster name. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can rename context using

```
kubectl config rename-context old-name new-name
```

for example in your case

```
kubectl config rename-context kubernetes-admin@cluster.devops cluster.devops
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please update the status pf question you can mark answer.